# black wire only hot on one end

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

Can someone explain to me why my wire is hot on only one end. The attached image shows my current wiring configuration.
[image: wiring example]

I'm using a voltage tester. When the switch is off only the bottom screw is reading hot. When switch is on both screws read hot.

Comment: How are you measuring the voltage?  Have you verified that you have good connections at both ends?

Comment: Is it possible that by some chance you measured "hot" on the wrong switch terminal and the switch is in the "off" position?

Comment: I'm using a voltage tester. When the switch is off only the bottom screw is reading hot. When switch is on both screws read hot.

Answer (score 3):

The only possible answer is the black wire to the light is broken.

Comment: Thanks. I just ran new wire today so not sure how it would be broken but I'll check it out.

Comment: @user157833   Good chance if you wiggle that wire the light will be on/off.

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect a poor connection (equalling a lack of connection) from the switch screw that reads hot to your non-contact tester to the wire you think is hot there. So the screw is hot, but the wire probably is not.

A break in the wire (or a bad junction if there are any, but you don't show any) is the other possibility, but **far more rare** than a bad connection. Typical cause for a poor connection would be getting the wire insulation clamped by the screw, rather than the actual copper wire.

A multimeter would offer more definitive testing, including continuity of the wire, but working with what you have, recheck that connection (breaker off first, of course)